# Can't access web folder after typing a chmod command (error 403)

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

So I was having issues with Root not being able to use fopen/fwrite through PHP and tried typing this hoping it would help (found it on another site)

chmod -R 766 /var/www/html

Andddd now I can access the domain through my web (http://x.x.x.x) but can no longer get to http://x.x.x.x/foldername or anything inside it

Sorry for the stupid question but how do I fix this? I'm new with Ubuntu stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant both read and write permission to the protected directory with sudo. I suggest you do this on just the project not the whole `/var/www/html` directory.
Here you go, on your terminal type
`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html` and then it should ask you for password because you used `sudo`, enter your system's password, you most likley won't see the password as you're typing, that's also fine just carry on and hit enter. Then run your php project again.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!! Hopefully helps others with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I`ll explain about correct file permissions for www. First find what user and group apache is using. Www files should have owner is user who edit the files, and group from apache. Permissions should be "rw" for user, "r" for group, and folders should also have X permission. For folders used by php to write something add "w" permission for group.

Find user name used by apache: `ps -aux|grep apache` You`ll see something like www-data

Change ownership to you and group: `sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data /var/www`

Change permissions: `chmod` -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /var/www

Add write access for scripts to certain folders, what used as cache or similar: `chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/templates_cache`
Do it for each folder what in need for write access.